# Generate database query based on email string

Tags: mysql, email, automation, exchange-server

I'm looking for a way to enable a user to send an email and get an auto-reply from a MySQL database based on the subject or body of the email.

A simplified example would be:
User emails status@domain.com with subject line Order Status 102934 and gets an auto-reply from a database with the ship date associated with order #102934.

Any articles/tutorials on something that might allow me to accomplish this would be great. Not sure if there is some relatively creative way to have exchange auto forward to a script or php and accomplish this? I realize I can simply accomplish through a web form but am not interested in that method for this application.

Comment: What conditions would you apply, before sending the auto reply?

Comment: Not following on what your asking.

Comment: Can anybody send an mail to this mail address with an Order Status in the subject line and get an automatic answer?

Comment: Yes, not needing to authenticate user/email or exclude data based on the originating email address, for this particular application. It'll mainly be internal use only where originating email would be on the same domain. If I opened up to a few more users in the future I imagine I can handle exclusions/inclusions through exchanges/firewall depending on the implementation method you are thinking about.

Comment: You could have a peek at [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx)